# How to display array values in input box

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

I am using appended below script to display multiple input box as per customer needs, as the name is same, so all values are saving in database in an array form. i want to display these values in input boxes once customer save his form. suppose if customer generate three input boxes and set values 1. abc 2. def 3. ghi, how to generate 3 input fields on page load and put these values in it?? i am new to javascript, any help is highly appreciated. Here is my codes:
`$value = "abc,def,ghi"`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
   
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="new_field_5[]" placeholder="Description"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        
    });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="new_field_5[]" placeholder="Description" value="<?php echo $value;?>"></div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Ajax request to the php file which returns all of the values for the inputs, and then use a for in loop to assign those values to each input

Comment: Thanks for quick response, as i am new in jquery and ajax. could you please give me an example code to retrive these values using ajax in loop

Comment: This should give a good look on how the process could be :

```js
$.post('test.php', function(response) {
        //Create a json Object
        const obj = JSON.parse(response);

        //Let's loop over every entry inside of the array
        for(let data in obj) {
            //Append the data with the back-end values
            $('#results').append('<input type="text" name="myName" value="'+obj[data]+'" >');
        }
    })
```
Now in your back-end you can provide the values:

```$array = [1,2,3];
echo json_encode($array);```